# Do you think 'hands-on' is redundant in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> Coming from a design and technical background, I believe ......
>
> Coming from a ***hands-on*** design and technical background, I believe ......

Comment: I'm not even sure if *a design and technical background* makes sense. How is *design* being distinguished from *technical*? By which, I mean that the phrase *technical design* is commonplace. I don't think I've ever heard them separated like this. On the other hand, both *a technical design background* and *a hands-on technical design background* make perfect sense.

Comment: If you do feel the need to distinguish between a practical and theoretical education, a better adjective suggests itself from that consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. A technical background does not require any hands-on experience. Think of an architect vs a builder. Technical can imply a merely theoretical background.